# App works fine in Expo-Go but doesn't work after EAS-Build

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo, eas

I have a simple app which uses react navigation v6. It doesn't use any other heavy third party libraries. All its using is **react-navigation-v6**. It works totally fine in **Expo-Go** during development but when i build a development apk with **eas build** it is stuck on loading screen always. The loading screen is my custom built component which i show at start to get data and authenticate user.

1. SDK: 46
2. PLATFORMS: Android

This is the command i use for building:

```
eas build --platform android --profile preview2
```

In the **preview2** profile i have set **buildtype** to **apk**